Modules versus standalone components
I have understood that in Angular 17 there is a tendency not to use modules even if they still exist and to make applications exclusively with standalone components, so it is more similar to Vuejs or React where there is no module in the concept. Additionally, a component
standalone in the compilation, it seems that the loading is more gradual and improves the performance of the Angular application, is this true?
My question is the following, is there a limit of standalone components to use in a component?
For example in my component "app.component.ts" I have the following:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, NavbarComponent, ButtonsBarComponent, FooterComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'front-end';

  constructor() {

  }
}

In the array of the "imports" property, can I continue importing Standalone components or do Angular's good practices impose any limits?
NOTE: If I do not create modules manually because I exclusively use standalone components, it would be feasible to use library modules such as Angular Material to use its UI components.

standalone component is effectively component + a module. there is no difference in just components usage, but there is a difference between the injectors trees that would exist in a standalone components apps and lazy modules ones. In most cases you just won't care about what is different here as standalone components injectors tree is simpler. just remember that module imports adds all of the imported moduels providers to the corresponding module injector, but component imports are just components/directive/pipes

Thanks, there is a limit set by the good practice when importing standalone components into another component?, as in the example: imports: [RouterOutlet, NavbarComponent, ButtonsBarComponent, FooterComponent], the last 3 components of the array are Standalone.

there is no something standalone specific. if your module had 500 items in it, the module itself would be really heavy both to read and to import. same is with standalone components

No, there is no limit to importing standalone components.
The only "limit" imposed by importing components is the bundle size that would be created. Thus making the app slower to load.
